Are pure quark stars possible?
Has it been established that structures formed from quarks (like quark stars: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_star) are possible in principle ?
I have read about the possibility that inside neutron stars matter may exist as a quark gluon plasma. But could this be extended to the entire star?
From the Wikipedia article that I linked, we can read

It is hypothesized that when the neutron-degenerate matter, which makes up neutron stars, is put under sufficient pressure from the star's own gravity or the initial supernova creating it, the individual neutrons break down into their constituent quarks (up quarks and down quarks), forming what is known as quark matter. This conversion may be confined to the neutron star's center or it might transform the entire star, depending on the physical circumstances. Such a star is known as a quark star.

But is this actually possible? Or just wikipedia garbage?

Wikipedia has plenty of garbage, to be sure, but that is in the minority, given the references adduced. Quark stars are a legitimate area of sound, imaginative, and often logically sound, speculation. You want a poll of opinions? Try some of the references cited, and Google-scholar-accessible papers citing those.

Voting to reopen. Definitely not opinion based. Quark stars, although hypothetical, are mainstream physics and we can say definite things about them and their properties.

There's a Kurzgesagt video on quark/strange stars, with these sources, several of which pertain to the feasibility of quark stars.

Thank you. All of the comments and answers in this question made me think about 3 questions: 1. are "bare" quark stars less established/more speculative than "dressed" ones? Or not necessarily? 2. Could these quark stars have high angular momentum (like neutrom stars)? 3. Is it possible that quark-gluon plasma or strange quark matter may be found somewhere else in the universe (not only as stars)? @J.G.


Near a star's surface, the pressure is low, so it comes down to how well you think quark matter can convert adjacent neutrons. 2. Neutron stars have the same angular momentum as before they collapsed, but high angular velocity because their radius has reduced so much. Quark stars will be alike. 3. Elsewhere it's so cold only escaped strangelets would qualify, but the presence on the still baryonic Earth of elements from neutron stars suggests escaped strangelets don't readily survive.


@J.G. thank you. And is it likely that quark matter could convert adjacent neutrons until transforming the entire star into a pure quark star? Or we simply don't know? And could strangelets survive if they were vompletely isolated and wouldn't interact with othe kinds of matter?

Although they are hypothetical objects, quark stars are definitely mainstream science and not just "Wikipedia garbage". Here is a 2018 paper about quark stars, including possible ways to detect them. It discusses both "bare" quark stars, where the entire star is made up of quark matter, and "dressed" quark stars, in which only the core of the star is made up of quark matter.
In 2002 NASA announced two quark star candidates - neutron stars/pulsars with unusual properties. One of these candidates (RXJ1856) is no longer thought to be a quark star, but the other (3C 58) still seems to be in the running.

Maybe add something about mechanisms that "might transform the entire star".

Thank you. I have 3 questions from your answer: 1. are "bare" quark stars less established/more speculative than "dressed" ones? Or not necessarily? 2. Could these quark stars have high angular momentum (like neutrom stars)? 3. Is it possible that quark-gluon plasma or strange quark matter may be found somewhere else in the universe (not only as stars)? @gandalf61
